# How to paginate array with nested groupings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination

I have following data grouped by color & quantity properties.

```
var data = {
  green: {
    "1000": [
      { type: 'apple', color: 'green', quantity: 1000 }, 
      { type: 'grape', color: 'green', quantity: 1000 }
    ]
  },
  red: {
    "2000": [
      { type: 'apple', color: 'red', quantity: 2000 }
    ],
    "4000": [
      { type: 'grape', color: 'red', quantity: 4000 }
    ]
  }
};
```

Now I want to paginate this data. So if page size equals to 1 item my first page will contain

```
 { type: 'apple', color: 'green', quantity: 1000 }
```

second:

```
 { type: 'grape', color: 'green', quantity: 1000 }
```

and so on. How could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You want to "flatten" the data first.** For this, you could use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the object values as an array. This would need to happen for each nested object. Then, optionally use `.flatMap()` and `flat()` or simply loop through the inner values and append to an array. (I prefer the flat methods because they avoid side-effects) Finally, some combination of other functionality to finish off the pagination...which will likely include [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

For example:

```js
const data = {
  green: {
    '1000': [
      {type: 'apple', color: 'green', quantity: 1000},
      {type: 'grape', color: 'green', quantity: 1000},
    ],
  },
  red: {
    '2000': [
      {type: 'apple', color: 'red', quantity: 2000},
    ],
    '4000': [
      {type: 'grape', color: 'red', quantity: 4000},
    ],
  },
}

// Flatten the list (still needs polyfill in IE/Edge today)
const items = Object.values(data).flatMap(
  color => Object.values(color).flat()
)
/*
// Alternatively...
const items = []
Object.values(data).forEach(color => {
  Object.values(color).forEach(list => {
    list.forEach(obj => {
      items.push(obj)
    })
  })
})
*/

const paginate = (items, page, pageSize) => {
  const startIndex = (page - 1) * pageSize
  const endIndex = Math.min(page * pageSize, items.length - 1)
  return items.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
}

console.log(paginate(items, 1, 2))
console.log(paginate(items, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can transform the data into an array, and then create a pagination function.

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) can be used to put all values in an array. [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) can be used to create a pagination function which returns an object with page number as key and items to be displayed as values.

```js
var data = { green: { "1000": [ { type: 'apple', color: 'green', quantity: 1000 }, { type: 'grape', color: 'green', quantity: 1000 } ] }, red: { "2000": [ { type: 'apple', color: 'red', quantity: 2000 } ], "4000": [ { type: 'grape', color: 'red', quantity: 4000 } ] } };

var results = [];

Object.values(data).forEach(item => {
  Object.values(item).forEach(value => {
    results = results.concat(value);
  });
});

function paginate(results, pageSize) {
  let pages = {}, pageNum = 1, i = 0;
  let totalPages = results.length / pageSize;
  let rem = results.length % pageSize;      
  
  while (pageNum <= totalPages) {
    pages[pageNum] = results.slice(i, i + pageSize);
    i += pageSize;
    pageNum++;
  }
   
   if (rem > 0) {
     pages[pageNum] = results.slice(i);
   }
   
  return pages;
}

console.log("Page size of 1:");
console.log(paginate(results, 1));

console.log("Page size of 2:");
console.log(paginate(results, 2));

console.log("Page size of 3:");
console.log(paginate(results, 3));
```